# Regex help, should be really simple

Tags: php, regex

```
$newHTML = str_replace("<tr><td>1-30 of 699 results.1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8-15 &Acirc;&middot; Next &Acirc;&middot; Last</td></tr>", "", $newHTML);
            $newHTML = str_replace("<tr><td>31-60 of 699 results.First &Acirc;&middot; Prev &Acirc;&middot; 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8-15 &Acirc;&middot; Next &Acirc;&middot; Last</td></tr>", "", $newHTML);
            $newHTML = str_replace("<tr><td>61-90 of 699 results.First &Acirc;&middot; Prev &Acirc;&middot; 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8-15 &Acirc;&middot; Next &Acirc;&middot; Last</td></tr>","",$newHTML);
            $newHTML = str_replace("<tr><td>91-120 of 699 results.First &Acirc;&middot; Prev &Acirc;&middot; 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8-15 &Acirc;&middot; Next &Acirc;&middot; Last</td></tr>","",$newHTML);
            $newHTML = str_replace("<tr><td>121-150 of 699 results.First &Acirc;&middot; Prev &Acirc;&middot; 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8-15 &Acirc;&middot; Next &Acirc;&middot; Last</td></tr>","",$newHTML);
```

The code above is me doing it without regex because I simply do not understand regex.

```
**<tr><td>**121-150 **of 699 results.First &Acirc;&middot; Prev &Acirc;&middot; 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8-15 &Acirc;&middot; Next &Acirc;&middot; Last</td></tr>**
```

Using above as an example, 121-150 are the only numbers that aren't constant in `$newHTML`. The rest of the string appears numerous times. How can I wildcard those spots? ie.

```
<tr><td>###-### of 699 results.First &Acirc;&middot; Prev &Acirc;&middot; 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8-15 &Acirc;&middot; Next &Acirc;&middot; Last</td></tr>
```

Where the number signs are possible numbers that need to be removed.

Comment: Post some sample input strings and desired output strings.

Comment: Sorry, the four str_replace uses I have are what I want to convert into regex. The string is inputted there.
There are multiple instances of that same string, but the only thing that changes is where it says 1-30, 31-60,91-120 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to convert your set of strings to a PHP regular expression. The considerations are:

`\d+` stands for 1 or more digits, so you'll use that in place of each number.

`\|` stands for a vertical line, so you'll use that in place of each vertical line.

Consequently, a regular expression which will match the given set of strings is:

```
<tr><td>\d+-\d+ of \d+ results.First &Acirc;&middot; Prev &Acirc;&middot; 1 \| 2 \| 3 \| 4 \| 5 \| 6 \| 7 \| 8-15 &Acirc;&middot; Next &Acirc;&middot; Last</td></tr>
```

Comment: Small error on that line: Unknown modifier '<'. Any ideas?

Comment: In PHP, you need to surround the regex with delimiters (try `#` before and after the regex).

Comment: Tim is right. What I posted is just the regular expression, not the PHP code around it.

Comment: +1 For understanding the question.